# Accessing a hubcontext instance in asp.net core signalr

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

i'm following a [guide](https://www.codemag.com/article/1210071/The-Simplest-Thing-Possible-Creating-Push-Notifications-with-SignalR) for setting up signalr for my asp.net core project.

While following this guide, I have this snippet of code:

```
void SendMessage(string message)
{
   GlobalHost
  .ConnectionManager
  .GetHubContext&lt;NotificationHub&gt;().Clients.sendMessage(
message);
}
```

I have a `NotificationHub` file that looks like so:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
    public string Activate()
    {
        return "Monitor Activated";
    }
}
```

Globalhost is used to get a `Hubcontext` object.
The issue is that When I import signalR, nothing called `GlobalHost` is available. In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-5.0) I can find this info about it:

```
GlobalHost

ASP.NET Core has dependency injection (DI) built into the framework. Services can use DI to 
access the HubContext. The GlobalHost object that is used in ASP.NET SignalR to get a HubContext 
doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core SignalR.
```

ok, so `Globalhost` is simply not available in core.

I need to do the same code, but for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;`.

How can I get a hold of a `Hubcontext` object now?

**EDIT**

I have now tried following the very minimal example from the documentation, and create a small sample project.
My ``startup.cs`file has this line, in`ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSignalR();
```

and this line in `Configure`:

```
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/Hubs");
    });
```

and my Hub file looks like this, as seen in the documentation:

```
namespace mvcCoreSample.Hubs
{
    public class NotificationHub : Hub
    {
        public Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            return Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Where Hubs, is a folder in the same directory as startup.cs.
I have a controller that looks like this, which calls the hub:

```
public class msgController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        NotificationHub hub = new NotificationHub();
        hub.SendMessage("user1", "some message");
        return Content("serving content");
    }
}
```

But when I run this, and go to the url of the controller, the hub throws an error in the `sendmessage` function:

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub.Clients.get returned null.
```

I really can't see where I am going wrong, something must be missing from the hub? perhaps something with setting up a connection?

**EDIT 2**

After a few corrections, I changed my controller to look like this:

```
public IActionResult Index(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
{
    var clients = hub.Clients;
    return Content("serving content");
}
```

Even though I still did not know how to call my `sendmessage` function, I wanted to try this.

When running this site in debug mode, I get this error thrown in the browser:

```
InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.IHubContext`1[[mvcCoreSample.Hubs.NotificationHub, mvcCoreSample, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Alternatively, give the 'hub' parameter a non-null default value.
```

Comment: You dont have to create an instance of `NotificationHub` by yourself. Inject `IHubContext<NotificationHub>` in your controller's constructor. The thing is that when you create your own instance - it doesnt contain any users. Hubs are singleton and they persist the connections

Comment: great thx! the only final problem now is that if I switch it out now, so the controller looks like `Index(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)`, then I can't write `hub.sendmessage` because it says that `IHubContext<NotificationHub>` does not contain a definition for `sendmessage`?

Comment: I now ran the example as is, and it fails

Comment: Use `hub.Clients.All.SendAsyn(...)` directly. Or, you can see how to use strongly typed hubs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#strongly-typed-hubs

Comment: Please, read the documentation properly!

Comment: yes, doing this fails. Passing in the arguments to the controller actions fails with the error I have described in the edit. This is true for both the index action and other actions that I might add

Comment: I've told you to inject that in the constructor. Why is that injected in the `Index` method?? It's not a constructor at all. You should learn some basics before trying to deal with `asp.net-core` and `signalr`

Comment: thx a lot, it now finally works. Thanks for the patience. I'm noting that. If you still have the energy, do you know where I can observe the message that is being sent to me from the server?

Comment: Follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject it in a constructor of your service like this:

```
SomeService(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hub)
```

You are probably looking at some old documentation. Please, check the official docs here: [Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: hmm, all right, the snippet I showed was supposed to just be placed somewhere in the homecontroller. Where Should i put the ``someservice` example?

Comment: Constructor of a class, that owns your  `SendMessage` method. Probably `HomeController` in you case

Comment: ok, so just to be certain, my homecontrollers constructor should then take IHubContext as a an argument? The thing that is confusing me, is that I dont understand how that argument would be passed?

Comment: Framework will handle it for you via dependency injection. You'll have to configure it to work properly, check the `Configure SignalR hubs` section of the documentation I referred to

Comment: I've tried to go through the code in the documentation. It straight up does not work at all, and steps are missing. Do you know of any fully working minimal examples?

Comment: None of the steps are missing there. It simply would not exist, if it was not working. You are definitely missing something

Comment: I just added an edit with the things I did. I really can't figure out what I'm doing wrong, and really need to have something wokring